# Ubuntu 14.04.5 x64 - Perforce Helix and LAMP Server?

Tags: 14.04, mysql, php, lamp

Hello im currently using an Ubuntu 14.04.5 x64 hosted online only for for versioning Unreal Engine 4 projects. I installed via terminal (Putty) the Helix Visual Client (P4V) also known as Perforce for this service, everything works fine.

Now i need to create a database MySQL and the HTTP server, LAMP if im correct, to processes the PHP files to bridge the data.

I am not aware of how Ubuntu behaves, because i come from another area, sorry for my ignorance.

Is it possible to have these two servicess/software on the same server, or i will need make a repartition or any such process on Ubuntu to have these services working properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LAMP and [Helix Visual Client (P4V)](https://www.perforce.com/downloads/helix-visual-client-p4v) can be installed on the same OS without requiring any special partitioning and without them interfering with each other. The latest version of Helix Visual Client was released in 2018, so it's probably compatible with the latest software packages from the default Ubuntu repositories. Because you would be paying a lot for the Helix Visual Client software, you would probably be interested in running the latest Long Term Support release 18.04 instead of 14.04.